# ¿Cómo obtener el mismo resultado de esta función para calcular el hash con sha1 y codificarla en base 64?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, base64

En PHP uso:

```
$hash = base64_encode(sha1($password.$key, true).$key);
```

Y en Node.js yo utilizo estas líneas para hacer un nuevo hash pero...  no tengo los mismos resultados que con php

```
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(password + key).digest('base64');
```

Comment: Lección: *nunca* concatenes strings con + _a menos_ que ese sea el operador nativo para el tipo string del lenguaje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puntualmente el problema que pude ver es que en `PHP` al usar [`sha1`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sha1.php) y establecer `$raw_output = true` (segundo parámetro), **el resumen sha1 será devuelto en formato binario**.

Es por esto que en `NodeJS` al generar el hash `SHA1`, al resultado también es en necesario convertirlo a `binary` (o `Latin1` que es lo mismo).

Intenta hacerlo así

- [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html)

  ```
  // Generamos el SHA1, lo convertimos a 'binary'
  var sha1 = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(password + key).digest('latin1') + key;
  // Encodeamos a Base64
  var hash = new Buffer(sha1, 'latin1').toString('base64');
  ```
- [crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js)

  ```
  // Generamos el SHA1, lo convertimos a 'binary'
  var sha1 = crypto.SHA1(password + key).toString(crypto.enc.Latin1) + key;
  // Creamos un WordArray para poder hacer el encode de la nueva cadena
  var wordArray = crypto.enc.Latin1.parse(sha1);
  // Encodeamos a Base64
  var hash = crypto.enc.Base64.stringify(wordArray);
  ```

Comment: gracias Marcos Gallardo asi mismo es

Answer (score 0):

En tu javascript trata esto:

```
var thePhrase = password.concat(key);
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(thePhrase).digest('base64')
```

[Aquí](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/90203/why-is-so-bad-for-concatenation) hay una pregunta en inglés al respecto

Comment: Nota: concatenar strings con el operador `+` se considera mala práctica en muchos lenguajes, para eso se han hecho los métodos convenientes.